# Does BizTalk Server support AES encryption for SMIME messages?

Tags: biztalk

In the following MSDN page it states the encryption algorithms that are supported by BizTalk 2010

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559843(v=BTS.70).aspx

*"BizTalk Server supports RSA and Diffie Hellman encryption certificates.*

BizTalk Server supports Data Encryption Standard (DES), 3DES, and RC2 encryption algorithms."

My question is - Can BizTalk also support SMIME messages encrypted using the newer AES encryption algorithm?
3DES is getting quite old now and is getting replaced by AES so I'm wondering if BizTalk has built in support for it yet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally got an answer that Biztalk does not currently support AES encryption.

We are now looking into alternative workarounds to solve this issue..